# Does body scroll event in iframe occur according to body tag of iframe or body tag of parent page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Does body scroll event in iframe occur according to body tag of iframe or body tag of parent page?
I have added an event in page and this will occur on body. but this page is loaded with iframe and will this event will occur to that page body tag and or parent page body tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested it, and when you scroll inside of an `iframe`, no `scroll` event is fired in the document containing the `iframe`.